# What is significance/use of doing void(param); at the start of function?

Tags: c++, c

I was just going thro' source code of Yahoo's Trafic Server
It is written in C++.

In almost all methods (from one of modules),
they do void(param) on each param that function receive.
(Eg below)

Can someone explain what this could be for ?

```
int                                                                                                                                                                     
some_method_name(caddr_t addr, size_t len, caddr_t end, 
 int flags)
{  
  (void) end;                                                                                                                                                
  (void) addr;                                                                                                          
  (void) len;                                                                                                                                                   
  (void) end;                                                                                                                                               
  (void) flags;  
  ......
  ....
}
```

PS:
For actual source code, please see methods from 
http://github.com/apache/trafficserver/blob/trunk/iocore/eventsystem/SocketManager.cc

Comment: Edited. When posting code samples, format them with the "Code sample" button (zeros and ones).

Comment: In C++ you can do that: `int some_method_name(caddr_t addr, size_t, caddr_t, int)` if you're not using some parameters.

Comment: That doesn't help if code, e.g. controlled through build flags, *might* use the parameters (here `#if (HOST_OS == linux)`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This suppresses the "unused argument" warnings. Those statements do nothing, but count as using the argument.